# Apache2: 429, Too Many Requests response

Tags: apache2, http-status-code-429

My Apache returns a 429 error code when I start using my API intensively. De API calls are generated by SAP BusinessObject and send to my 'Reverse Proxy' to convert HTTP to HTTPS. The Reverse Proxy forwards the HTTP request to the webserver over HTTPS.

After 15 requests, the Reverse Proxey returns a 429 error in the Apaches error.log. These 15 requests are made within 9 minutes.

How can I configure Apache so it will handle this kind of load/traffic? Becase I've another 300 requests after the first 15...

**Reverse Proxy config:**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
ProxyRequests Off

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias domain.com

        SSLProxyEngine On
        SSLProxyVerify none
        SSLProxyProtocol SSLv3
        ProxyPass / https://domain.com/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://domain.com/

        <Directory proxy:*>
                Order Deny,Allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: 15 requests sounds to me awfully like the maximum number of concurrent connections in a default configuration. Are you sure your connections are being closed properly? Do you have a very long keep alive?

Comment: It is a default Apache configuration. Using the command "netstat -anpt|grep apache2 |grep ESTABLISHED" during the proces I see two active connection from the Reverse Proxy to the webserver and for every request from SAP BO to the ReverseProxy a conenction is established and closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An update in de webserver was the problem. The vendor replaced their webserver and put a limit of 5 requests per minute in the software...

This was not mentioned in the release notes.

Thank you for he time and sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 2):

I am no Apache expert.
But, I'd give the following a try (in the apache config):

```
# wait up to 300 seconds for slow clients
TimeOut 300
# allow connections to be reused between requests
KeepAlive On
# allow a maximum of 100 requests per connection
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
# wait up to 15 seconds for the next
# request on an open connection 
KeepAliveTimeout 15
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have enabled mpm module you can increase the maxThread.

You can see the documentation for installing and setup in here:

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-apache-mpm-prefork-to-improve-performance/