# Http 429 Too many Requests Apache

Tags: php, laravel, apache, wamp, http-status-code-429

I have got an installed WAMP Stack with Apache 2.4.23, PHP 5.6.25 and MySQL 5.7.14. On this server there is a small PHP Laravel application which only serves as a Web-Service-API for inserting Data. When we try to insert Data evey 300 Milliseconds, after about 1 minute we get a 429 Too Many Requests Error. Does anybody know which settings i could change to prevent this Error?

Edit: The Data is inserted from one client only which might lead to this error, although we are inserting tons of measure data from this client!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache2: 429, Too Many Requests response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632645/apache2-429-too-many-requests-response)

Comment: i already found this post although no change when modifing the settings. i thought apache would be suitable for a lot of concurrent requests!